# Unhandled rejection when importing string constants rather than declaring them locally

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a React-Redux thunk action that retrieves categories from an API server then adds them to the Redux store:

(categoryActions.js)

```
export const fetchCategories = () => dispatch => (
  CategoryAPI.getCategories().then(categories => {
    for(const category of categories) {
      const {name, path} = category
      dispatch(addNewCategory(name,path))
    }
  })
)
```

It works fine when using it with the following API call:

(categoryApi.js)

```
const apiServerURL = "http://localhost:3001"

const headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'whatever-you-want'
}

export const getCategories = () => (
  fetch(`${apiServerURL}/categories`, { headers })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => data.categories)
)
```

However, when I try to define the API constants in a different file like so:

(apiConstants.js)

```
export const HEADERS = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Authorization': 'whatever-you-want'
}
export const SERVER_URL = "http://localhost:3001"
```

and then use them in categoryApi.js:

```
import {
  HEADERS,
  SERVER_URL
} from './apiConstants'

export const getCategories = () => (
  fetch(`${SERVER_URL}/categories`, { HEADERS })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => data.categories)
)
```

I get the following error from line 3 of the thunk action in categoryActions.js above:

> Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property
>   'Symbol(Symbol.iterator)' of undefined

What's the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your variable is capitalized, so you need to set the property correctly, because `fetch` expects it lowercase:

```
export const getCategories = () => (
  fetch(`${SERVER_URL}/categories`, { headers: HEADERS })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => data.categories)
)
```

--

```
{ headers }
```

is equivalent to:

```
{ headers: headers }
```

So in your second example you have it capitalized:

```
{ HEADERS: HEADERS }
```

This is known as [property shorthand](http://es6-features.org/#PropertyShorthand)